# React js fetch request abort not working when using setState function in then response

Tags: reactjs, fetch, abort

without setState abort request works fine but
could not abort asyc request when using setState on fetch then function. following I have mention code that  i was playing around.

```
let controller;
let signal;

const [stateRefresh, setStateRefresh] = useState(true);
const [cancelReq, setCancelReq] = useState(false);


const startFetch = async() => {
    controller = new AbortController();
    signal = controller.signal;

    for (var i = 20 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
        fetch(url, { signal })
          .then((response) => {
            setStateRefresh(!stateRefresh);
            console.log("Download complete", response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Download error: ${err.message}`);
        });
    }
} 

const stopFetch = async() => {
     controller && controller.abort();
}


return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={ startFetch }>start</button>
    <button onClick={ stopFetch }>stop</button>     
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Every variable in the component will be destroyed when the component is rerendered. You can't just use `let signal;`, you have to use state or ref

Comment: Tried using signal on state no luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [controller, setController] = useState();
const signal = useRef();

const [stateRefresh, setStateRefresh] = useState(true);
const [cancelReq, setCancelReq] = useState(false);


const startFetch = async() => {
    let newController = new AbortController();
    setController(newController )
    signal.current = cont.signal;

    for (var i = 20 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        let url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
        fetch(url, { signal: signal.current })
          .then((response) => {
            setStateRefresh(!stateRefresh);
            console.log("Download complete", response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Download error: ${err.message}`);
        });
    }
} 

const stopFetch = async() => {
     if(controller){
        controller.abort();
     }
}


return(
    <div>
    <button onClick={ startFetch }>start</button>
    <button onClick={ stopFetch }>stop</button>     
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).